How to place a long text in the center
I need to center person's name and surname in my Container widget. Here is my code:
Container(
  width: 130,
  height: 40,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    color: Colors.red,
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
  ),
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Icon(Icons.supervised_user_circle),
      Flexible(
        child: Text('MyName Surname'), // exactly two lines
      ),
    ],
  ),
),

I added Flexible widget so that the long text fits into the widget. The size of the container should be exactly like this.
How can I center this icon and two lines?

You can use \n to insert a line break.
Text('MyName Surname') becomes Text('MyName\nSurname')
Before:

After:

Does this accomplish what you're looking for?

This is a good way for this particular case, but what about when the data comes from the server? In this case, it will no longer be possible to add a line break.

Is there any specific format of the text you receive?

@AkhilSuthapalli I get two words in one variable - first name and last name, which are separated by a space

You can use the .split() operator, then.
